# Prove or give a counterexample of limsup and liminf

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Lets $a_n$ and $b_n$  be two sequence that $0\leqslant a_n \leqslant 1$ and $0\leqslant b_n\leqslant 1$ for each $n$.

Prove or give a counterexample that:

a) if $\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = 1$  then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$

b) if $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = 0$  then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$

I was trying to find a counterexample for hours and it's not working, I'd like to get a tip or anything...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For the second one, consider $(a_n)=(1,0,1,0,1,0,...)$ and $(b_n)=(0,1,0,1,0,1,...)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(a)** Clearly, we have : $0 \leqslant a_nb_n \leqslant a_n \leqslant 1$. Therefore, $$1 = \displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n \leqslant \displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n \leqslant 1$$ implying : $\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n= 1$

Again, $$1 \geqslant \displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n \geqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$$ implying : $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n =  \liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$

Hence, we must have $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1$ .

---

**(b)** As per *J. W. Tanner*'s comment above, take $\{a_n\} = (1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , \cdots)$ and take $\{b_n\} = (0 , 1 , 0 , 1 , \cdots)$ .

Then, $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_nb_n = 0$ , but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ does NOT exist.

Comment: +1. For (a) I would prefer to write "$1\le \lim\inf a_nb_n\le\lim\inf a_n\le\lim\sup a_n\le 1,$ implying $1\le \lim\inf a_n\le\lim\sup a_n\le 1,$ implying $\lim a_n=1.$"

Comment: Another way for (a) is that if $a_n$ did not converge to $1$ then  there would exist $r>0$ such that $a_n\le 1-r$ for infinitely many $n.$ But then $a_nb_n\le a_n\le 1-r$ for infinitely many $n$, contrary to $\lim\inf a_nb_n=1$.